# Strange behavior when debugging Eclipse CDT with Eclipse Debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

When debugging Eclipse CDT code I witnessed a strange behavior. I try to explain it with screen-shots. I am sure people who don't know CDT can still give me an answer to this question, because I think it's related to (debugging) Java code with Eclipse in general.

The `IIndexFile file` you see in the highlighted line will have a field with a wrong value and I try to understand where that value comes from.

Before entering `getFile()`:

[image: getFile() will be called]

Inside `getFile()` a new `PDOMFile` is created. The constructor with two parameters is called:
[image]

Shortly before leaving the constructor we can see on the right side that `location` is null. Not surprising, as it hasn't been set yet.
[image]

The next image shows the first thing that surprises me a bit. When leaving the constructor for `PDOMFILE` I actually expect the debugger to tell me the return value. Instead it says `No explicit return value`. Maybe it's because it was a constructor or maybe it's because of the if-statement.
[image]

Now the highlighted line shows that the dubber is back from the call `getFile()`, but the assignment to `file` hasn't been done yet. We can see that the `location` field is still null.
[image]

And this is what I don't understand. Why is `location` from file set now?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger calls `toString()` to obtain the string displayed in the bottom pane of the "Variables" view. `PDOMFile.toString()` calls `getLocation()` which sets `location` on its first call.

Comment: That almost drove me mad. It never occured to me that `toString()` sets variables.